# Why did upgrading RDS from Postgres 10.11 to 11.6 cause a storage-full error?

Tags: postgresql, storage, amazon-rds

I have a RDS Postgres database on version 9.6.6, and was tasked with upgrading it to version 11.

To do this, I created a snapshot and then provisioned a new 9.6.6 database. Next, I clicked "modify" in the RDS console and upgraded this new instance to version 10.11. Once it was on major version 10, RDS then allowed me to upgrade again to version 11.6.

However, within an hour of completing this process, the new 11.6 database seized up and entered into the `storage-full` status. The following CloudWatch event was produced right before this happened...

> The free storage capacity for DB Instance: my_new_db is low at 2% of the provisioned storage [Provisioned Storage: 4.78 GB, Free Storage: 77.81 MB]. You may want to increase the provisioned storage to address this issue.

Both the old and the new database are allotted 5GiB of disk space. I don't believe the size of my database tables are a factor, since the following query returns 330MB, which is only 7% of the allotted space.

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('my_old_db'));
```

Since the size of my database tables clearly isn't the culprit, **what could have possibly caused my RDS instance to run out of disk space?**

*Specs:

Instance class: db.t2.medium

Ram: 4GB

vCPU: 2

Encryption: Enabled

Storage type: General Purpose (SSD)

Storage: 5GiB*

Comment: Depending on how the upgrade was done, maybe the data from the old version is still lying around?

Comment: The new database instance was created from a snapshot of the old instance. So yes, in that sense, all of the old data is still laying around and that is to be expected. However, the old data is not duplicated twice and taking up double space. The old database and new database are completely separate instances.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently when upgrading a 9.6.22 DB instance in-place to 13.3.

The instance had only 5 GB storage, with a DB that was roughly 2.5 GB, and disk space decreased rapidly after upgrade to about 1 GB (within an hour or so), then stabilised.  There was no disk-full error but storage was about 80% used.

- I went through the [RDS 'disk full' troubleshooting page](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/diskfull-error-rds-postgresql/) which didn't help as the extra storage was not within the Postgres database cluster (i.e. set of DBs in this instance).
- The mitigation was to resize this into a DB instance with over 20 GB storage.

I believe both issues may be down to the increased minimum size of storage for RDS instances - at some point, AWS must have increased this from 5 GB to 20 GB.  See [this section of AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html#Concepts.Storage.GeneralSSD) and the AWS Console for RDS when creating a new instance.

I would say there is an RDS issue here, as the console or API should tell you that you need to increase the size of storage before upgrading - similarly to how it may tell you that current instance type is not supported for upgrade.